How can I extend an interface with generic type in `typescript`?
I am using typescript 5.1.6 in a nodejs project. I have below code:
export interface ExecutionResult<TData = { [key: string]: any }, TExtensions = { [key: string]: any }> {
  errors?: ReadonlyArray<any>;
  data?: TData | null;
  extensions?: TExtensions;
}

export interface MyExecutionResult<
  TData = {
    [key: string]: any;
  },
> extends ExecutionResult {
  data?: TData | null;
}

It has an interface ExecutionResult and I extends it in MyExecutionResult. But it gives me compiling error on MyExecutionResult:
Interface 'MyExecutionResult<TData>' incorrectly extends interface 'ExecutionResult<{ [key: string]: any; }, { [key: string]: any; }>'.
  Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'TData | null | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; } | null | undefined'.
      Type 'TData' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; } | null | undefined'.
        Type 'TData' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.ts(2430)

It works fine if I use extends on TData as below:
export interface MyExecutionResult<
  export interface MyExecutionResult<
  TData extends {
    [key: string]: any;
  },
> extends ExecutionResult {
  data?: TData | null;
}

what I don't understand why it complains about the code when I use TData = ...? I don't see much different between = and extends in this context.

You don't see the difference between a generic constraint and a generic default? Why not? They're different things and behave differently.  I mean, this code is equivalent to what you've written. Do you see why the good one is okay and the bad one is not? I'm trying to understand where the disconnect is for you.

Maybe it should be: MyExecutionResult<TData = { [key: string]: any }> extends ExecutionResult<TData>

Wll extends defines generic constraint generic arguments will need to satisfy.
TData = ... is a default value for the generic argument. They no mutually exclusive, for instance this is still valid: type Result<TData extends { [key: string]: any } = { [key: string]: number }>
